# Unable to view APP (DB) file under AppData on downloading the App container for IOS9

Tags: core-data, ios9

Life was good before I upgraded my device to IOS 9 and noticed that APP (Core Data-DB) file under AppData directory is not available anymore in downloaded (App) Container using xCode.
I am unable to view the APP Core Data (device DB) using SQL Lite. Please guide.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's still there.

In Xcode 7, just use the gear menu and choose "Download Container..."

[image]